# Prove that a given binary operation on a list that reduces an (arbitrary) pair at a time always results in the same single element (contest question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, contest-math

*I believe I have proven part (a), but would like some feedback on whether(and how) this should be made more rigorous (especially at the end), and whether there is a simpler way that doesn't involve steps like the associativity computations.*

From the 2007 Canada National Olympiad

> For two real numbers $a, b$, with $ab \ne 1$, define the **$\ast$ operation** by
>
> $a \ast b = \dfrac{a + b − 2ab}{1 − ab} \tag{1}$
>
> Start with a list of $n \ge 2$ real numbers whose entries $x$ all satisfy $0 < x < 1$.
>
> Select any two numbers a and b in the list; remove them and put the number
>   $a \ast b$ at the end of the list, thereby reducing its length by one. Repeat this procedure until a single number remains.
>
> a. **Prove that this single number is the same regardless of the choice of pair
>   at each stage.**
>
> b. Suppose that the condition on the numbers x is weakened to
>   0 < x ≤ 1. What happens if the list contains exactly one 1?

---

### Part b.

For any $a$ we have

$a\ast1 = 1\ast a = \dfrac{a+1-2a}{1-a} = \dfrac{1-a}{1-a} = 1$ since $a<1$

So the one cannot be eradicated, and the list will eventually reduce to the single element $1$.

### Part a.

My ideas on how to approach part a:

1. Find an invariant for the list, e.g. if the operation was $\square$ with $a \square b = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, the invariant would be "sum of squares of list elements" as this would be unchanged by the operation.
2. Use some inductive argument(s) to show that the symmetry between variables in (1) is also present in formulae for $a \ast (b \ast c)$ and $(a \ast b)(c \ast d)$, and so on.
3. Show commutativity (trivial) and associativity, and argue that this allows brackets and terms (in an expression where $\ast$ always operates on the last two terms) to be moved at will, so will always allow say an expression where terms are consumed from the right to be re-ordered in the original list sequence, e.g. $c\ast(b\ast a) \equiv a\ast(b\ast c)$

---

#### a1. Invariant Method

There is nothing obvious here, as the denominator in (1) complicates matters. This will only get worse with further reductions of terms.

#### a2. Symmetry between Variables

This will probably involve some real drudgery, and may not even be workable.

---

#### a3. Commutativity and Associativity Method (the Proof)

We will first prove **closure** as this will prevent nasties such as division by zero, etc.

Suppose we have $a,b|0<a<1\text{ and }0<b<1$. Then for $c=a\ast b$:

$c = a\ast b = \dfrac{a + b − 2ab}{1 − ab} = 1 - \dfrac{(1-a)(1-b)}{1 − ab} \tag{2}$

Then by AM-GM we have

$a+b>2ab \implies -a-b+1+ab<-2ab+1+ab \implies (1-a)(1-b)<1-ab$

Then $0<a,b<1$ means $0<1-ab<1$ and $(1-a)(1-b)>0$ so we conclude $0<c<1$.

Now for **commutativity**. Well, by (1):

$b\ast a = \dfrac{b + a − 2ba}{1 − ba} = \dfrac{a + b − 2ab}{1 − ab} = a\ast b$

As to **associativity**, we have for general $a,b,c$ in the list:

$\begin{align}
a\ast(b\ast c) = a\ast\left(\dfrac{b+c−2bc}{1−bc}\right) &= \dfrac{a+\dfrac{b+c−2bc}{1−bc}-2a\dfrac{b+c−2bc}{1−bc}}{1-a\dfrac{b+c−2bc}{1−bc}} \\ \\
&=\dfrac{a(1-bc)+b+c−2bc-2a(b+c−2bc)}{(1-bc)-a(b+c−2bc)} \\ \\
&=\dfrac{a+b+c-2ab-2ac-2bc+3abc}{1-ab-ac-bc+2abc} \tag{3}
\end{align}$

and

$\begin{align}
(a\ast b)\ast c = \left(\dfrac{a+b−2ab}{1−ab}\right)\ast c &= \dfrac{\dfrac{a+b−2ab}{1−ab}+c-2\dfrac{a+b−2ab}{1−ab}c}{1-\dfrac{a+b−2ab}{1−ab}c} \\ \\
&= \dfrac{a+b−2ab+c(1-ab)-2c(a+b−2ab)}{(1-ab)-(a+b−2ab)c} \\ \\
&= \dfrac{a+b+c−2ab-2ac-2bc+3abc}{1-ab-ac-bc+2abc} \tag{4}
\end{align}$

Since the expressions in (3) and (4) are identical, $\ast$ is associative.

Suppose we have the list $a,b,c,d$ and the sequence of operations given by: compute $f=a\ast b$, compute $g=d\ast c$, compute $h=g\ast f$

Thus for the result $r$:

$r = g\ast f = (d\ast c)\ast(a\ast b)$

but this equates to:

$\begin{align}
r &= (d\ast c)\ast(a\ast b) \\
  &= (a\ast b)\ast(d\ast c) &(\text{commutativity})\\
  &= (a\ast b)\ast(c\ast d) &(\text{commutativity})\\
  &= (a\ast (b\ast(c\ast d)) &(\text{associativity})\\
\end{align}$

which we can view as a sort of canonical format where the operations proceed strictly right to left and the symbols are in the same sequence as the original list. We could write

$r=a\rightarrow b\rightarrow c\rightarrow d$

to emphasise this.

Lists with two elements are trivial and do not require associativity.
We claim that, for a general list, commutativity and associativity always allow the desired rearrangement of operations and elements into the canonical form, so all orderings of operation sequences for a given list are equivalent. ${\blacksquare}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine for both parts.

The invariant is more difficult to find, but here is a hint:
$$\frac1{1-a*b}-1 = \left(\frac1{1-a}-1\right) + \left(\frac1{1-b}-1\right)$$

Comment: Please explain the strong induction step to me. I cannot see why it follows that $a\ast(b\ast c)$ is symmetric in $a,b$? Or is there an argument that $(d\ast a)\ast(b\ast c)$ is symmetric in $a,b,c,d$ and then take $d=0$ which is the identity element (I know it's not in the domain, but ...).

Comment: You're right, symmetry alone will not do it. The function defined for invariant can be used, as it is strictly  monotone, so induction on it will carry over. However that's not as simple as the symmetry I suggested first.